# Ocultar linha inteira de tabela por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa noite, estou tentando ocultar por javascript uma linha inteira da tabela abaixo, podem me ajudar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pode ser com jquery, ou quer javascript mesmo? E qual linha voce quer ocultar? tipo eu digito um numero e oculto?

Comment: to tentando fazer em javascript mesmo, pode ocultar a primeira linha, e teria um comando pra ocultar e mostrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo desse tipo?

```js
function ocultar() {
  var total = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  var linha = document.getElementById("linha").value;
  if (linha > 0 && linha < total) {
    if( document.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(linha).style.display=="none"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(linha).removeAttribute("style");
    }
    else{
 document.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(linha).style.display="none";}
  } else {
    alert("essa linha não existe");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    th,
    td {
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="linha">
  <input type="button" value="Ocultar/Desocultar" id="remover" onClick="ocultar()">
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To tentando fazer aparecer a linha, mas ela nao esta alinhando corretamente

Comment: quando conseguir mando aqui

Comment: mas está ocultando corretamente, porém o que estou tentando fazer agora é exibir novamente

Comment: quando conseguir eu encerro a duvida

Comment: eu consegui, pera ai vou editar

Comment: editei, da uma olhada. se colocar o mesmo numero ele desoculta a linha

Comment: funcionou tudo, obrigado mesmo pela ajuda

Comment: boa noite kkkkk

Comment: Foi um prazer ajudar, boa noite kk

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito de fazer isso é utilizando o **querySelectorAll()** (disponível tanto no Document como no Element)

Essa função retorna uma array de elementos pelos quais que você pode iterar.

Você pode, por exemplo, definir uma função que recebe um *id* e um *índice* e oculta a linha, se esta existir, com o estilo *display*.

```
function ocultaLinhaTabela(id, n) {
  var seletor = "#" + id + " tr";
  var linha = document.querySelectorAll(seletor)[n];

  if (linha) linha.style.display = "none";
}
```

No contexto da sua tabela: https://jsfiddle.net/qf9ped94/